# Can we automate downloading of PDF files from a website

Tags: hadoop, automation, python-requests

Before proceeding to do this task, i would like to know if the below given ideas can be executed or if there is any other means of doing this like in hadoop

1. Can we try downloading the PDF's from a website such that every time a new file is added it gets automatically downloaded (without intervention or running a script) and the file is saved in google drive.

2.Can we do it in Python or is there any other programming language required.

Comment: Totally depends on the use-case scenario that how you are going to use it. If it is test automation purposes I would recommend a basic local file tracker to check and download if there's any new file but this solution **will require** manual or jenkins run. Please provide more information for use-case.
To save it to google drive is another story you can check this document for implementing api from google https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk.

Comment: Thank you for the information @Turquase this is for creating a repository of documents so that we can have the files get saved locally without any manual intervention as and when the new file is added in the website

Comment: This is the link http://bbmp.gov.in/en/covid19bulletins